# How do I configure the COMMITEMEOUTS so the read function doesn't return until the whole message is read?

Tags: c++, windows, io, serial-port, timeout

I am using ReadFile function to receive serial data, for certain msgs I can only read them partially before the time out is over. I would like to configure the COMMITEMEOUTS variables so that the Read Function doesn't return until there is data coming in from the serial port.
Earlier I was using this configuration which would some time rad partial data

```
sUartCfgParam.sReadTimeout.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant   = readTimeoutConstant;//250ms
sUartCfgParam.sReadTimeout.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
sUartCfgParam.sReadTimeout.ReadIntervalTimeout        = 0;
```

Now I have changed the values to:

```
sUartCfgParam.sReadTimeout.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant   = 0;
sUartCfgParam.sReadTimeout.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
sUartCfgParam.sReadTimeout.ReadIntervalTimeout        = readIntervalConstant;//10ms
```

For the second configuration the ReadFile function never returns. What am I doing wrong over here?What would be the correct config. for my requirement?

Comment: It is an impractically low value.  But sets the timeout between *two* bytes, it will block when no byte has been received.  If you never want to block then you must set it to MAXDWORD.  There is no value you can use the read "the whole message", serial ports are not message oriented.  Nothing but a simple byte stream, not unlike TCP.  Turning the received bytes into a "message" is something you have to do yourself.  Generally it requires a protocol so you can reliably detect the start of the message and get the transmitter and receiver reliably synchronized.

Comment: Exactly, when I say message I mean I want the ReadFile function to boock until all the bytes in a stream are read. In my mind the interval timeout should have done the trick but it blocks for ever. I do have a protocol that returns false when the number of bytes expected are not the same as number of bytes received in that case it just does read again.what I want to do is rather than reading again if not all bytes are received is wait until all of them are.